# Is window.__INITIAL_STATE__ still the preferred way to pass initial state to the client in React Universal apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-universal

I'm currently reading [a book](http://amzn.to/2p4bfsE) about React and Universal apps in which the author claims that the following is best practice to pass initial state from server to client:

**server.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {renderToStaticMarkup} from 'react-dom/server';
import Myapp from '../MyApp';
import api from '../services';

function renderPage(html, initialData) {
    return `
        <html>
            <body>
                ${html}
            </body>
            <script>
                window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(initialData)};
            </script>
            <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        </html>
    `;
}

export default function(request, reply) {
    const initialData = api.getData();
    const html = renderToStaticMarkup(<MyApp />);
    reply(renderPage(html, initialData);
}
```

And then, in the client you would read out the data like this:

**bundle.js**

```
const initialData = window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {};
const mountNode = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, mountNode);
```

From what I understand is that the initial state first gets converted to a string and then attached as a global object literal to the window object.

This solution looks very rough to me. The book was released in mid 2016. Is usage of `window.__INITIAL_STATE__` still the way how to do this or are there better solutions?

For example, I could imagine that it would be possible to offer the initial state in a separate micro service call which then could also be cached better than if the data is embedded directly into the document because then the initial state data has to be transferred every time the page refreshes, even if the data hasn't changed.

Comment: [Yes](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md). Your micro-service is a viable approach, but you need to weigh the pros/cons of making an extra HTTP request vs. piggy-backing off the HTTP request you made to serve the page. If your state is constantly in-flux outside of the client-side environment and you are making a lot of server-round trips then perhaps micro-service would be beneficial. Then again, you might want to ask why you're refreshing the page so often too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simple answer: Yes.

But I'm not sure why no one has pointed out that you have a very common XSS vulnerability using `JSON.stringify(initialData)` what you want to do instead is to:

```
import serialize from 'serialize-javascript';

 window.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ${serialize(initialData)};
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP works by caching responses, in your case, if the initial state will always be the same, you can also cache this in server side and display it in the page, it will work faster, because react will have access immediately to this value so it will not have to wait. Also you can also force the browser to cache the page, so the response for the page will be the same with the initial state not changing.

With the extra call request, you rely on the browser to cache that call, but you'll have to build an extra step, make react re-render when the information arrives or block react to render until the information is ready.

So I'll go with number 1, gives you more flexibility and some other nice to have, like server rendering, which can be easily achieved after having the state loaded in the server.